# Store the numpy array in csv or excel

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have a numpy array data as given below:

```
array([array([ 90.48600884,  97.36925515,  99.90243902, ...,  77.08908407,
       119.06976744, 107.22513089]),
       array([79.27741935, 87.77142857, 87.14893617, ..., 59.36231884,
       97.52380952, 87.39687055])], dtype=object).
```

I want to store this data into a .csv or .excel file. When I am using the usual approach like 
np.savetxt('test.csv',hr,delimiter =',',fmt = '%s'), it is saving the data in the same way as displayed above means I am not able to access the middle number. Is there any way to store the given numpy array in excel or in csv file so that I can access all the numbers?.

Comment: Please include a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: `savetxt` is designed to write a 2d numeric array.  You have a 1d object dtype array.  You have to first convert that to the right kind of array.  For a start try `np.stack(arr)`.  If it works, verify the `shape` and `dtype`.

Answer (score 0):

don't have your full array but that works for me:

```
import numpy

var = [([ 90.48600884,  97.36925515,  99.90243902, 77.08908407,
       119.06976744, 107.22513089]),
       ([79.27741935, 87.77142857, 87.14893617, 59.36231884,
       97.52380952, 87.39687055])]

np_var = numpy.asarray(var)

numpy.savetxt("foo.csv", np_var, delimiter=",")
```